# Dynamically attach file input into form - not working in Safari / Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form on my page that has validation to determine whether a file was included or not. If no file is selected and the form submitted, I should get a warning displaying:

> "Attachment can't be blank"

I am using [this ajaxupload plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) ([github source](https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload/blob/master/ajaxupload.js)) to allow a user to click on an image and enable the file dialogue to pop-up.

This is what happens:

1. User selects a file
2. File input is copied and attached to the form as a hidden input

With all browsers. When I inspect my form element, I can see the file input:

```
<form ....>
<input type="file" name="song[attachment]" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; font-size: 480px; font-family: sans-serif; cursor: pointer; ">
</form>
```

FF and Opera work fine. But Safari and Chrome complain that the file input is blank. i.e. triggering the validation:

> "Attachment can't be blank"

But why is Safari and Chrome acting differently? Can I not dynamically attach input elements into the form before submission with these two browsers? Perhaps Safari and Chrome finds it as illegal syntax to rewrite the file input after the form element is loaded?

PS. Haven't tested this yet on IE, since I am on a mac.

Comment: Can you show your manipulations with file inputs (copy-attach stuff) and validation code? Provided code seems to have little relevance to  me, as it's executed after successful validation.

Comment: Nikita, you mean rails code? I refrained from showing rails code, sice I thought this was more a problem with the js plugin and safari/chrome. However, if you still need the rails code, I can paste them in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a security issue with Safari/Chrome. I moved the element instead of cloning it. Seems to work now